# how to split a text file into multiple list based on whitespacing in python?

Tags: python, list, split, tokenize

hi i'm new to python programming, please help me to create a function that taken in a text file as an argument and creates a list of words thereby removing all punctuation and the list "splits" on double space. What i mean to say is the list should create subsists on every double space occurrences within a text file.

This is my function:

```
def tokenize(document):
    file = open("document.txt","r+").read()
    print re.findall(r'\w+', file)
```

Input text file has a string as follows:

```
What's did the little boy tell the game warden?     His dad was in the kitchen poaching eggs!
```

Note: There's a double spacing after warden? and before His

My function gives me an output like this

```
['what','s','did','the','little','boy','tell','the','game','warden','His','dad','was','in','the','kitchen','poaching','eggs']
```

Desired output :

```
[['what','s','did','the','little','boy','tell','the','game','warden'],
['His','dad','was','in','the','kitchen','poaching','eggs']]
```

Answer (score 0):

At first split the file by punctuation, and then on the second pass split the resulted strings by spaces.

```
def splitByPunct(s):
    return (x.group(0) for x in  re.finditer(r'[^\.\,\?\!]+', s) if x and x.group(0))

[x.split() for x in splitByPunct("some string, another   string! The phrase")]
```

this yields

```
[['some', 'string'], ['another', 'string'], ['The', 'phrase']]
```

Comment: how do i apply split() function on the derived list after the first pass ? can you please write this module for me so that i can understand..

Answer (score 0):

First `split` the whole text on **double spaces** and then pass each item to `regex` as:

```
>>> file = "What's did the little boy tell the game warden?  His dad was in the kitchen poaching eggs!"
>>> file = text.split('  ')
>>> file
["What's did the little boy tell the game warden?", 'His dad was in the kitchen poaching eggs!']
>>> res = []
>>> for sen in file:
...    res.append(re.findall(r'\w+', sen))
... 
>>> res
[['What', 's', 'did', 'the', 'little', 'boy', 'tell', 'the', 'game', 'warden'], ['His', 'dad', 'was', 'in', 'the', 'kitchen', 'poaching', 'eggs']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonable all-RE's approach:

```
def tokenize(document):
    with open("document.txt") as f:
        text = f.read()
    blocks = re.split(r'\s\s+', text)
    return [re.findall(r'\w+', b) for b in blocks]
```

Comment: A generator approach would be better here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, considering that the multiple spaces can occur anywhere, reading the file in blocks with proper overlap would be horrendously complex -- yet that's the only potential advantage of a generator, dealing with files so huge you don't have enough memory otherwise.  So "better" is in the eyes of the beholder -- is a very complex, bug-prone, long function potentially able to deal with huge files (that were never specified in the Q) "better" than a simple, short, obviously correct one?  Plus, the Q very explicitly specified **lists** as output, so, O(N) memory mandatorily anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin split function allows splitting on multiple spaces.

This:

```
a = "hello world.  How are you"
b = a.split('  ')
c = [ x.split(' ') for x in b ]
```

Yields:

```
c = [['hello', 'world.'], ['how', 'are', 'you?']]
```

If you want to remove the punctuation too, apply regex to elements in 'b' or to 'x' in the third statement.